# Google Column Chart with two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-api, google-visualization

How to approach a [column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) when having month and year.

My data is in this format

```
['Group','Count','Month','Year'],
['A',10,'February',2015],
['B',8,'February',2015],
['C',15,'February',2016]
```

Aim is to create a column chart which has **X-axis as Month** and **Y-axis as Count**. Now X-axis should have Count for years grouped by month.
Something like this - [image]

I tried to simply pass the above data to see what I can get, but I get error.

Any way to assign Axis the values based on year grouped by month ?

**[JsFiddle of Google Chart Example](https://jsfiddle.net/_pirateX/L3fmdn2r/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just need three columns, something like this...

```
  ['Month', '2015', '2016'],
  ['Jan', 10, 15],
  ['Feb', 12, 18],
  ['Mar', 14, 21],
  ['Apr', 16, 24]
```

then you can use a `DataView` to add the annotations, via calculated columns...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', '2015', '2016'],
      ['Jan', 10, 15],
      ['Feb', 12, 18],
      ['Mar', 14, 21],
      ['Apr', 16, 24]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
      }, 2, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 2,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    }]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, {});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

all google charts require a specific [DataFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format)

meaning, manipulation is required if your data does not already exist in this format

the visualization library does offer some [Data Manipulation Methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data), such as [`group()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group)

which could be used to transform the data into the required format

> 1) group the data by Month and Year
>   2) create a new DataTable with the Month column
>   3) add a column for each Year from the grouped table
>   4) add the rows for each month

see following working snippet, using the data from the question...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Group', 'Count', 'Month', 'Year'],
      ['A', 10, 'February', 2015],
      ['B', 8, 'February', 2015],
      ['C' , 15, 'February', 2016]
    ]);

    // group by month / year
    var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,
      [2, 3],
      [{column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number', label: 'Count'}]
    );
    dataGroup.sort([{column: 0},{column: 1}]);

    // build final data table
    var yearData = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Month', type: 'string'}
      ]
    });

    // add column for each year
    var years = dataGroup.getDistinctValues(1);
    for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
      yearData.addColumn(
        {label: years[i], type: 'number'}
      );
    }

    // add row for each month
    var rowMonth = null;
    var rowIndex = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataGroup.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (rowMonth !== dataGroup.getValue(i, 0)) {
        rowMonth = dataGroup.getValue(i, 0);
        rowIndex = yearData.addRow();
        yearData.setValue(rowIndex, 0, rowMonth);
      }
      for (var x = 1; x < yearData.getNumberOfColumns(); x++) {
        if (yearData.getColumnLabel(x) === dataGroup.getValue(i, 1).toString()) {
          yearData.setValue(rowIndex, x, dataGroup.getValue(i, 2));
        }
      }
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(yearData);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
      }, 2, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 2,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    }]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
    chart.draw(view);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: But with this approach I'd have to add a column every year. Any other way to approach it ?

Comment: each chart requires a specific format, so some manipulation required -- see __EDIT__ to above answer...

Comment: Can I use another column for annotations?