# Google apps charts for data grouped on two columns

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I can't seem to be able to to get a chart for the following grouped data where column 0 is Year and Count is the number of each item in Column 1 in each year:

```
var aggrData = google.visualization.data.group(
            data, [{
                'column': 0,
                role: 'domain'
            },{
                'column': 1,
                role: 'annotation'
            }], 

            [{
                'column': 1,
                'aggregation': google.visualization.data.count,
                'type': 'number',
                'role': 'data',
                'label': 'Count'
            }]);
```

I would love to have a chart as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703689/google-column-chart-with-two-columns) but with grouped data as above. My snippet that doesn't work is as follows:

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard1_div'));
dashboard.bind([independantFilter1, dependantFilter1], [barChart1]);
dashboard.draw(aggrData);
```

Comment: could you please share a sample of the `data`?

Comment: Before Grouping
==============================

Year          Student
2000  Student1
2001  Student2
2001  Student2
2002  Student1
2002  Student1
2002  Student1
2002  Student1
2002  Student1
2002  Student3
2002  Student3
2002  Student3
2003  Student4

After grouping
================================

Year           Student      Count
2000           Sudent1      1
2001           Student2     2
2002           Student1     5
2002           Student3     3
2003           Student4     1

Comment: I could not attach an image. My above comment should  give an idea when formatted on a text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to mimic the chart referenced in the link,
need to first build a data view, with a column for each student
then aggregate on each student column

the data table has a method --> `data.getDistinctValues(1)`
this will return an array of unique students

which can be used to build columns for the view and the group

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Student'],
    ['2000', 'Student1'],
    ['2001', 'Student1'],
    ['2001', 'Student2'],
    ['2001', 'Student2'],
    ['2002', 'Student1'],
    ['2002', 'Student1'],
    ['2002', 'Student1'],
    ['2002', 'Student1'],
    ['2002', 'Student1'],
    ['2002', 'Student2'],
    ['2002', 'Student3'],
    ['2002', 'Student3'],
    ['2002', 'Student3'],
    ['2003', 'Student4']
  ]);

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var students = data.getDistinctValues(1);
  var viewColumns = [0];
  students.forEach(function (student, index) {
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === student) {
          return 1;
        }
        return null;
      },
      label: student,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });
  dataView.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var aggColumns = [];
  students.forEach(function (student, index) {
    aggColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: index + 1,
      label: dataView.getColumnLabel(index + 1),
      type: dataView.getColumnType(index + 1)
    });
  });

  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dataView, [0], aggColumns);

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
  chart.draw(dataGroup, {
    legend: 'bottom'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot WhiteHat. It seems hard to get it working by drawing it with the google.visualization.Dashboard object. I wanted to bind filters that way.

Comment: don't follow exactly, but if the filters are applied before the grouping occurs, you may need to use the dashboard controls independently, without binding them, then use the `'statechange'` event to know when something has changed and perform the grouping, [similar to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38851678/5090771)